# Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that I am trying to convert to MySQL from MS SQL Server 2008. It runs fine on MSSQL,
I get the error 
"`Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'`".

How do I solve this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    dbo.`@EIM_PROCESS_DATA`.U_Tax_year,
    dbo.`@EIM_PROCESS_DATA`.U_Employee_ID,
    CASE
        WHEN dbo.`@EIM_PROCESS_DATA`.U_PD_code = 'SYS033' THEN SUM(dbo.`@EIM_PROCESS_DATA`.U_Amount)
    END AS PAYE,
    CASE
        WHEN dbo.`@EIM_PROCESS_DATA`.U_PD_code = 'SYS014' THEN SUM(dbo.`@EIM_PROCESS_DATA`.U_Amount)
    END AS TOTALTAXABLE,
    dbo.OADM.CompnyName,
    dbo.OADM.CompnyAddr,
    dbo.OADM.TaxIdNum,
    dbo.OHEM.lastName + ', ' + ISNULL(dbo.OHEM.middleName, '') + '' + ISNULL(dbo.OHEM.firstName, '') AS EmployeeName
FROM
    dbo.`@EIM_PROCESS_DATA`
        INNER JOIN
    dbo.OHEM ON dbo.`@EIM_PROCESS_DATA`.U_Employee_ID = dbo.OHEM.empID
        CROSS JOIN
    dbo.OADM
GROUP BY dbo.`@EIM_PROCESS_DATA`.U_Tax_year , dbo.`@EIM_PROCESS_DATA`.U_Employee_ID , dbo.OADM.CompnyName , dbo.OADM.CompnyAddr , dbo.OADM.TaxIdNum , dbo.OHEM.lastName , dbo.OHEM.firstName , dbo.OHEM.middleName , dbo.`@EIM_PROCESS_DATA`.U_PD_code
```

MySQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     processdata.taxYear, processdata.empID, 
     CASE WHEN processdata.edCode = 'SYS033' THEN SUM (processdata.amount) END AS PAYE, 
     CASE WHEN processdata.edCode = 'SYS014' THEN SUM (processdata.amount) END AS TOTALTAXABLE, 
     company.companyName, company.streetAddress, company.companyPIN, employeemaster.lastName + ', ' + IFNULL(employeemaster.middleName, '') 
     + ' ' + IFNULL(employeemaster.firstName, '') AS EmployeeName
FROM         
     processdata INNER JOIN
     employeemaster ON processdata.empID = employeemaster.empID 
     CROSS JOIN company
     GROUP BY processdata.taxYear, processdata.empID, company.companyName, company.streetAddress, company.companyPIN, 
     employeemaster.lastName, employeemaster.firstName, employeemaster.middleName, processdata.edCode
```

Comment: Where is your MySQL Query ?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The MySQL equivalent of [ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) is [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

> If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns
>   expr2.

Maybe also look at [SQL NULL Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

[The ISNULL from MySQL is used to check if a value is null](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull)

> If expr is NULL, ISNULL() returns 1, otherwise it returns 0.

Comment: it is only for 1 condition, YES / NO..if need to use more than one use COALESCE

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you switch to the ANSI standard function `coalesce()`:

```
(dbo.OHEM.lastName + ', ' + coalesce(dbo.OHEM.middleName, '') + '' + coalesce(dbo.OHEM.firstName, '')
) AS EmployeeName
```

You could also make your query easier to read by including table aliases.

EDIT:

As a note, I seemed to have missed the direction of conversion.  The MySQL query would use `concat()`:

```
CONCAT(OHEM.lastName, ', ', coalesce(OHEM.middleName, ''),
       coalesce(concat(' ', OHEM.firstName), '')
      ) AS EmployeeName
```

Comment: I've a similar kind of problem.. Can you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147569/how-to-return-null-as-0-from-mysql-using-hibernate-criteria

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error when running JUnit tests against a query which had `ISNULL(value)` with the error saying ISNULL needed two parameters. I fixed this by changing the query to have `value is null` and the code works the same while the tests now work.