# Simplify and correct following query

Tags: mysql, simplify

How do I fix, and possibly simplify I guess, this SQL query, please?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
   M IN (NULL,1) AND T IN (NULL,1) AND J IN (NULL,1) AND B IN (NULL,1)
   AND (ISNULL(M,0)+ISNULL(T,0)+ISNULL(J,0)+ISNULL(B,0))<4
   ORDER BY (ISNULL(M,0)+ISNULL(T,0)+ISNULL(J,0)+ISNULL(B,0)) DESC
```

`table` contains 4 columns `(M,T,J,B)` with 3 possibles values only `NULL, 0, 1`.

- First-line filters to get only entries containing `NULL` or `1`.
- Second-line makes an addition to get the total of `M+J+T+B` and filters only `if <4`.
- Third-line `ORDER BY` the same Total, `M+J+T+B`.

error `#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'`

MySQL equivalent to `ISNULL` is `IFNULL`... [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21381011/3916429)

Comment: 1) tag your database 2) provide sample data and desired output

Comment: ISNULL is a SQL Server function but your error message looks to be MySql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from (
    select *, coalesce(M,0) M2, coalesce(T,0) T2, coalesce(J,0) J2, coalesce(B,0) B2
    from table
    where 
     (M is null or M=1) and
     (T is null or T=1) and
     (J is null or J=1) and
     (B is null or B=1) 
)x
where M2+T2+J2+B2 < 4
order by M2+T2+J2+B2 desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Nulls act strangely in SQL.  **Any** comparison test with a null will result in FALSE, so if you use the phrase Null=Null in a where clause, nothing will be retrieved because the result is always false.  I would rewrite your second line to use IsNull functions instead,

```
IsNull(M,1)*IsNull(T,1)*IsNull(J,1)*IsNull(B,1)>0
```

Comment: thank you, i am probably missing something but i am already trying to use `ISNULL`. Something is wrong anyway in my 2nd and 3rd lines. The 1st one is fine. But i am not used to `ISNULL` and doing additions on a request at all... I tried your approach, but my request is probably not a correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
 t.*,
 coalesce(M,0) + coalesce(T,0) + coalesce(J,0) + coalesce(B,0) as calc
from table t
where 
 coalesce(M,0) in (0,1) and
 coalesce(T,0) in (0,1) and
 coalesce(J,0) in (0,1) and
 coalesce(B,0) in (0,1) and
 calc < 4
order by calc desc
```